# "Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed" msg in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I try to make a simple test

```
import 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import App from '../src/App';
import {render} from '@testing-library/react-native';

// Silence the warning https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11094#issuecomment-263240420
jest.mock('react-native/Libraries/Animated/src/NativeAnimatedHelper');

it('renders correctly', async () => {
  const {findByText, findAllByText} = render(<App />);
  const homeText = await findByText(/home/i);
  expect(homeText).toBeTruthy();
});
```

But when it run I get the below msg

```
Jest did not exit one second after the test run has completed.

This usually means that there are asynchronous operations that weren't stopped in your tests. Consider running Jest with `--detectOpenHandles` to troubleshoot this issue.
```

In a web enviroment, I saw that could be resolve stopping some service like `mongoose.close()` for example, but here in RN idk what it is the thing that should stop to resolve that message. Could you help me please?

EDIT: this pic show console run with `--detectOpenHandles` flag
[image]

And the code is below

`HomeScreen.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity, View} from 'react-native';
import {useQuery} from 'react-query';
import {routes} from '../utils/routes';
import {getBirras} from '../utils/services';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}) => {
  const {data, error, isLoading} = useQuery('/beers', getBirras);
  const itemStyle = {color: 'black', fontSize: 26};

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Text>Cargando...</Text>;
  }

  if (error) {
    return <Text>Error al cargas birras</Text>;
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Text>Home page {data && data.length}</Text>
      {data && (
        <FlatList
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.name}
          data={data}
          renderItem={({item}) => {
            return (
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() =>
                  navigation.navigate(routes.detailsPage, {id: item.id})
                }>
                <Text style={itemStyle}>
                  {item.name} - {item.id}
                </Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            );
          }}
        />
      )}

      <Button
        title="Go to detail"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate(routes.detailsPage)}
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

`DetailScreen.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
import {useQuery} from 'react-query';
import {getABirra} from '../utils/services';

const DetailsScreen = ({route}) => {
  const {id} = route.params;

  const {data, error, isLoading} = useQuery(['detailBirra', id], getABirra);
  
  return (
    <View style={{color: 'black'}}>
      {data && (
        <>
          <Text style={{color: 'black'}}>Slogan: {data[0].tagline}</Text>
          <Text>Description: {data[0].description}</Text>
        </>
      )}
    </View>
  );
};

export default DetailsScreen;
```

`services.js`

```
import Config from 'react-native-config';

export const getBirras = async () => {
  try {
    const data = await fetch(`${Config.API_URL}/beers`);
    return data.json();
  } catch (error) {
    throw error.response;
  }
};

export const getABirra = async ({queryKey}) => {
  try {
    const data = await fetch(`${Config.API_URL}beers/${queryKey[1]}`);
    return data.json();
  } catch (error) {
    return error.response;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you try `npm test --detectOpenHandles` and if there's any logs

Comment: I try that flag, but there is no any extra log, the logs finish there :(

Comment: Must be some async operation in `<App>`. Can you share that file's code?

Comment: Yes, I have an api call in my home screen, just give me a moment to edit the post with the file's code

Comment: Any updates on this? I've been facing the same error lately.